# User email confirmation options?JWT?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, user-management, email-confirmation

1. I have a front end in react and a backend in asp.net core web api.
2. I have already a login with jwt tokens and register using hashing
   and salt to store in db.
3. I want to implement an email confirmation when the user registers in
   my site.
4. Should i use jwt to generate token and send this jwt in the email to
   user

Im not finding much solutions, need some suggestions

Comment: why would you email a token to a user, just to confirm they're registered?

Comment: i would email them like react-app.com/user/verify-email/{token} ,backend would see if token is valid and put true in db column

Comment: I m not finding other way of doing this email confirmation

Comment: what would u suggest? @AndreiDragotoniu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a typical way of building an email validation thing, with a one time code, would be to use a GUID. In the email you sent, add a link with this unique GUID attached at the end something like :

www.something.com/email-verify/877ebd19-6852-4de9-b228-4d796a4cd7c7

you create a table in your db where you store these generated tokens with the a user id so you know which user it is when they click the link, add a used flag so you know you only accept it once and you're pretty much done.

Comment: THANKS ur the man, there is not really a tutorial or video that explains what is the industry standard for this.Im really apreciated